# Git sync changes with remote master

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I pushed some changes to my remote Git master branch from another location, then on my local master repository I did some changes which edited some files and deleted others and now I have to merge these changes with the changes of the remote repository. The problem happens when I try to push the changes: my commit still uses old files which on the remote branch have been edited and updated. I don't understand how I should download the changes of the remote file and merge them with my changes

**EDIT 1**

This is the history of the repository. The 6fee6bf commit is an amend commit which adds a new file to the previous commit which was pushed to the remote repository

- aef9a19 (tmp-master) new commit 2
- 6fee6bf test commit
- 48ccbc4 (HEAD, origin/master, master) test commit
- 1f466df old commit
- f006d29 old commit x2
- aba1ce0 old commit x3
- 04f4a67 old comit x4
- e22f33b old commit x5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion would be to make sure you have everything committed on the current master, then create a new branch from there. Afterwards hard reset your local master to remote master. Then  either rebase or cherry-pick those changes. Something like the following:

```
git branch tmp-master
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Now you can use the following to easily visualize the differences between the two branches:

```
git log --decorate=short --oneline --graph --all
```

Cherry-picking the other commits and fixing conflicts as you go would probably be easiest, but you could also try a rebase. If you need more specific steps, let me know and I'll write 'em up.

Update:

Now that you're here, you can try (from `master`):

```
git merge tmp-master
```

But for cleaner commit history you may want to try the following:

```
git checkout tmp-master
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge --ff tmp-master
git branch -d tmp-master
git push origin master
```

This will take your local commits and reapply them on top of the remote changes. Since you're essentially doing the same work, but from two different machines, you probably don't want a lot of "well, switched machines again" merge commits.

Now, there may be some possible conflicts. There are a couple ways to take care of those. If you have a conflict and know your local changes take priority then do the following (assumed from the `tmp-master` branch, and have conflicts in the rebase):

```
git rebase --abort
git branch tmp-master-save
git rebase -X theirs master
```

Then check if everything looks good continue from the step `git checkout master` above. Also remember to delete the other `tmp-master-save` branch. Created it just for safe keeping. When you're new to this it's always better to have a safety mechanism.

Comment: I executed your commands and this is the situation: I now have a local tmp-master which from the logs seems to have the commits which I have to push to the remote (without the changes merged from it). The master branch has been hard-reset and is at the remote HEAD commit. Now, how can I merge the two branches?

Comment: @Stefano updated. let me know if that gets you where you want to go. if not, plenty more to do. difficult to say exactly when i don't know the exact state of the repo.

Oh, and I also forgot the important `--all` flag in the `git log` command above. very important so to see all your history.

Comment: I added the repository history to my question. I still can't get it working, the changes from the remote repository are lost and aren't get merged

Comment: @Stefano I'm a little confused. If you amended a commit to `6fee6bf` then pushed it to `origin`, then `origin/master` should be pointing to it. Are you sure it's pushed? As the history is listed there you should be able to `git checkout master` then `git merge --ff tmp-master` to get them in sync.

Comment: I amended the commit (I just added a missing file) but I didn't push it to the remote branch. Instead, I just committed it to my local repository

Comment: Have you tried the `merge --ff` command? if that didn't work, mind posting `git reflog | head -8`? that should give me enough information to see exactly what's been happening.

Comment: do you want before trying that command to push that amended commit to the remote repository?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25388/discussion-between-trev-norris-and-stefano)

Answer (score 0):

Before you push your commits, you must request for getting changes on the repository you can do it using git pull --rebase command. It will get changes and merge all it can do safely. If some troubles happend, it will say to you to correct conflict yourself, do it and continue the merging using git rebase --continue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do this:

```
git fetch origin

git rebase origin/master master --preserve-merges
```

The first command `fetch` would fetch information from the remote repo into your local repo. It would bring in all the changes but it would not merge them automatically with your local copy of any of your branches.

The rebase command would first go back to the common point between your local master and remote, do a fast forward merge of all the changes which came from the remote, then apply your changes on top of it. Using `--preserve-merges` creates a cleaner history if you have merges in your local copy between branches.

Comment: I tried it but the files that I edited have my local edits but they are not merged with the remote changes. When it rebased no errors happened, however it used only 2 commits while the changes which I need to pull are older

Comment: @stefano - Have you committed the changes you have done in your local copy ? If not you should be doing that and make sure `git status` reports no local changes before starting a `merge` or a `rebase`.

Comment: I commited the changes to my local repository (I didn't push them to the remote) and git status says that there is nothing to commit because my working directory is clean and that the branch is ahead of 2 commits. I tried everything but I can't get the changes of the remote repository merged with my local changes

Comment: @Stefano - Are you saying that not all changes were merged from the remote when you did a `rebase` ? Does `git log --all` show all the changes that you're interested in the remote ?

Comment: exactly, it didn't merged anything from the remote. The log shows all the remote commits and the local ones correctly. There is also a commit which is an amend (I forgotten to commit a file in a previous push to the remote branch and that should have added it).

Comment: I'm surprised that `rebase` does not give an error in your case if it cannot bring in all the changes. BTW I'm assuming your `remote` is called `origin` in the commands I mentioned. Is that correct ?

Comment: What happens if you run `git rebase --continue` ?

Comment: nothing happened, it started a new rebasing. It tries to rebase only 2 commits back but the changes I need are older. However, using HEAD~N doesn't work either

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening here. At this point, I would suggest to try the approach suggest by Trev. Making a local tmp branch which has all your changes, then hard rebasing your local master to be in sync with remote master and doing a merge from the local tmp branch into master sounds like a reasonable approach.